# calc digits/decimal places from resolution

Tags: matlab, octave

Is there an easy way to calculate the number of digits needed to display a floating point number with a given resolution? (Without going through string conversion)

```
resolution = [0.1 0.01 0.05 0.025 0.10001];

% first try
digits = -floor (log10 (resolution))

% wanted output
ex_digits = [1 2 2 3 5];
```

gives

```
digits =
   1   2   2   2   1
```

The first three results are fine but the other fails with my first attempt.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can multiply the number by powers of 10 and compare the result with its floor.

```
resolution = [0.1 0.01 0.05 0.025 0.10001];
k = resolution .* 10.^(1:20).';
[~, digits] = max(round(k)==k);
```

You may also use a tolerance to take into account precision errors:

```
r = round(k);
tol = eps(r) * 2;
[max_val, digits] = max(abs(r-k) < tol);
digits = max_val .* digits + ~max_val .* 20;
```

Comment: I would call this something like a "brute force" method: multiply by 10 until there is no fractional part.

Comment: This fails for many values like `[1.0+1.0e-9,1.23e-10]` and others due to floating point representation. You tolerance approach also doesn't work as you've described it

Comment: @Andy Answer updated using `round` instead of  `floor`. I hope that it would produce more accurate result.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this seems to come close enough:

```
ceil( log10( [~, D] = rat( resolution, eps ) ) )
```

Comment: Interestingly, 0.025 registers as a 2, whereas 0.024 and 0.026 register as a 3. If I tried hard I could probably sell this as 'bug as a feature' :p

Comment: It is the same for 0.000128 or 0.00625.